# R package installation error: relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11

Tags: c++, r, linux, gcc

I am trying to install an R package named 'quantreg' and 'igraph' by rstudio but is shows error:

> Here is what Rstudio console shows

```
    gcc -c -std=gnu99 --enable-shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o quantreg.so akj.o boot.o bound.o boundc.o brute.o chlfct.o cholesky.o combos.o crq.o crqfnb.o dsel05.o etime.o extract.o idmin.o init.o iswap.o kuantile.o mcmb.o penalty.o powell.o rls.o rq0.o rq1.o rqbr.o rqfn.o rqfnb.o rqfnc.o rqs.o sparskit2.o srqfn.o srqfnc.o srtpai.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
gcc: warning: akj.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: boot.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: bound.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: boundc.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: brute.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: chlfct.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: cholesky.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: combos.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: crq.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: crqfnb.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: dsel05.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: etime.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: extract.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: idmin.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: init.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: iswap.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: kuantile.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: mcmb.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: penalty.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: powell.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: rls.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: rq0.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: rq1.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: rqbr.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: rqfn.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: rqfnb.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: rqfnc.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: rqs.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: sparskit2.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: srqfn.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: srqfnc.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: srtpai.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
** R
** data
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘quantreg’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 shared object ‘quantreg.so’ not found
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed`enter code here`
```

in tried manual installation also but error remain same. 
Any Help please??

Answer (score 0):

You need a non-broken R installation which uses / has built R as a shared library (which then leads to `-fPIC` or `-fpic` being added to compilation as needed) as well as *shared libraries* of the required components, here Fortran.

Basically every Ubuntu or Debian installation (using the provided packages) is.  We don't know what you have here -- but you simply *cannot* use the statically compiled `libfortran.a` in a shared / dynamically-loadable module for R.

Comment: i am new to ubuntu. Please let me know what i can do

Comment: Try installing `r-base-dev`.  Maybe you just miss the corresponding `-dev` package for `libgfortran`.  You did not give sufficient information to say more.

Comment: How can i make a change in 'R CMD install' to recompile with -fPIC

Comment: Set `CFLAGS` or `CXXFLAGS`.  See the _R Installation and Administration' manual that came with R.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: I changed the' shared flag' and now i am getting the error as shown above. Please look

Comment: Your code (which you don't share) is probably wrong if it contain `main()`.  These are relatively basic errors, so maybe you should revisit some intro tutorials.

Comment: i solved that problem too by edit 'cc' in 'Makecong' file, Now the error is shown above. I just want to install package 'quantreg'

Comment: `sudo apt-get install r-cran-quantreg` gets you a binary. See this [README](http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu).  If you're on another Linux variant, see if it has binaries for you.

Comment: This command is for ubuntu 16.04. I am on ubuntu 14.04. didn't work